# Reg Ex for Hard Coding

Tags: regex

.* = '.*' shall be allowed  (e.g param = '01') 
but 
.* = '.*'(.*) should be prohibited. (e.g param = '01'(001))

I used the following regex .* = .*(?!(.*)) but it dint work.

Can u suggest a simple regex for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[^()]*$
```

this will not allow parenthesis

demo here :

https://regex101.com/r/tG4gN9/1

Comment: .* = ('.*'[^()]*$) . This works now

Comment: @vijaye good to know vijay, but please be a little clear with your questions next time you ask , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?='.*?'$
```

Add anchors to make it stop and not make partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

This is based off your example, in case you wanted to see why your lookahead was failing (escaped brackets and missing quantifier):

```
.* = '\w+'(?!\(.+\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/xX3eP2/1